# Show Error symbol under some text in textarea -similar to spelling error line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to add underline or some error symbol under some text in textarea ,similar to spelling error (red underline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do this type of rich text formatting with a simple `textarea`. I suggest you to search a JavaScript plugin for this. Take a look:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex16/richtexteditor/index.htm

Comment: but in textarea if you do some spelling mistakes ,you will see red underline under that text. cant i use something like that ??

Comment: No, this is a feature of your browser, there's nothing to do with you webpage, site etc..You can't control it. But what I and @MarcB suggest is you to create your own tool for that, I will upgrade your JS skills a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

No. a textarea is unformatted text. You cannot apply any styles to individual portions of it, only the entirety. For sub-portions of the text, you'll have to use a richtext editor which dynamically replaces the textarea with another element that has `contentEditable=true` enabled.